# which jar include com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential and where to get it?

Tags: java, azure-purview

I'm running following this [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/purview/azure-analytics-purview-catalog/src/samples/java/com/azure/analytics/purview/catalog/ListGlossaries.java) to test SDK of java on azure purview.
when I use javac to build this class, I got below error, it show I miss some classes
I wonder Where to get these classes? I search in [mvnrepository](https://mvnrepository.com/), but not found related jars.

[image]

here is my commandline:
javac -cp .\azure-identity-1.3.1.jar;azure-analytics-purview-catalog-1.0.0-beta.jar;azure-core-experimental-1.0.0-beta.14.jar;javax.json-1.1.4.jar ListGlossaries.java

actually ,the TokenCredential was imported in class [PurviewCatalogClientBuilder](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/main/sdk/purview/azure-analytics-purview-catalog/src/main/java/com/azure/analytics/purview/catalog/PurviewCatalogClientBuilder.java) , not sure why it cannot find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can download and in github https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java

Comment: thanks, I got this from azure-core jar https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/767952d2152d396e3699885c1e781ef6bdfc0237/sdk/core/azure-core/src/main/java/com/azure/core/credential/TokenCredential.java#L12

Answer (score 2):

using maven this should be:

```
<dependency>
<groupId>com.azure</groupId>
<artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
<version>1.3.1</version>
```

Comment: I didn't create maven project, I just create an test java file and build it to test the Java SDK , does this make sense?