# Microsoft Graph Java SDK ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, gradle, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

Here is my build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.azure:azure-identity:1.7.1'
    implementation 'com.microsoft.graph:microsoft-graph:5.42.0'
}
```

Here is my code (actual values are replaced with "...")

```java
final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
    .clientId("...")
    .clientSecret("...")
    .tenantId("...")
    .build();
final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
    List.of("files.readwrite.all"),
    credential
);
final GraphServiceClient client = GraphServiceClient
    .builder()
    .authenticationProvider(authProvider)
    .buildClient();
```

And once I run it I get a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.azure.core.credential.TokenCredential`

I tried to find a solution to this, but nothing seems to help.

Comment: please clean `./gradlew clean` and do build and check class is available from your classpath or not.

Comment: @Raushan Kumar the thing is it is not included in jar

Comment: please check if this helps
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68222826/which-jar-include-com-azure-core-credential-tokencredential-and-where-to-get-it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following code works:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredential;
import com.azure.identity.ClientSecretCredentialBuilder;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.TokenCredentialAuthProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;
import okhttp3.Request;

        final String clientId = "your client id";
        final String tenantId = "your tenant id";
        final String clientSecret = "your client secret";

        final List<String> scopes = Arrays.asList("https://graph.microsoft.com/.default");

        final ClientSecretCredential credential = new ClientSecretCredentialBuilder()
            .clientId(clientId).tenantId(tenantId).clientSecret(clientSecret).build();

        if (null == scopes || null == credential) {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected error");
        }
        final TokenCredentialAuthProvider authProvider = new TokenCredentialAuthProvider(
            scopes, credential);

        final GraphServiceClient<Request> graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder()
            .authenticationProvider(authProvider).buildClient();
```

My pom entries:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph</artifactId>
    <version>5.54.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-identity</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.35.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-auth</artifactId>
    <version>0.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.graph</groupId>
    <artifactId>microsoft-graph-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.18</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
    <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
    <version>4.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```